# Mongodb for Java(ADT), how to create connection?

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mongodb-java

This is the code that I was trying to error, and gave me an error.

```
try {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydatabase");
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("users");

        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("user_id", "5");
        document.put("user_name", "David");
        table.insert(document);

    } catch (MongoException e) {
        Log.w("PPERROR", e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.w("PPERROR", e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am really not sure if the database connection is actually made or not. 
mongo.exe is located in "C:\mongodb\bin" 
I executed mongod.exe with dbpath "C:\test\testdata"

```
mongod.exe --dbpath "C:\test\testdata"
```

And this gives me "waiting for connections on port 27017"
Lastly, the whole project is located in C:\users\david\workspace\projectName

When I run the code, I am getting an error

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 4936 ms
```

after this line of code

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("users");
```

I suspect that mongoClient failed to get db named "mydatabase".(or not even connected to localhost)
When I create mongoClient, is there anything that I can specify dbPath?

If my explanation is unclear, please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**
**This shows the database connection if I am correct.**

[image]

Comment: Can you connect to the database via the mongo shell?

Comment: take a look at this:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sculptorgenerator/PCyggfv01sg

Comment: @helmy I added the screenshot that shows my database connection via cmd.

Comment: @user3266530 according to the post you linked, am I correct that I have to change configuration?

Comment: So open another command prompt window and run the mongo shell (mongo.exe) to see if it can connect to your mongod.

Comment: Also, try turning Windows firewall (or any other firewalls) OFF.

Comment: @helmy Yes, I was able to connect to mongo.exe using cmd, but when I try to connect with java code above then it fails.

Comment: You mentioned ADT, have you tried running this in a non-ADT project? e.g. create a plain Java project and a simple class with main() and the code above.

Comment: Any solution? same problem here; by using an older java library (2.5) works.. do you also have an old version of mongodb running?